# How to traverse SimpleXML to edit text nodes?

Tags: php, simplexml, traversal

I need to implement the following algorithm with SimpleXML:

1. put a XML fragment string into a SimpleXML object;
2. traverse all the nodes, selecting text nodes;
3. edit the text node (example convert to upper case);
4. return the xml as string.

PROBLEMS:

- How to load a XML with named entities (ex. `&nbsp;`).
- To traverse XML to get only text nodes... With `$sx->xpath('//text()');` I can not edit the nodes, how to select text nodes to edition?

Comment: Why do you think named entities will be a problem / what problem have you encountered with them? As for text nodes, note that SimpleXML treats all the text content of an element as a single string, so is not well suited to data where elements have both element and text children (e.g. `<foo>some text <child /> some more</for>`). This might be a case where the DOM API would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes... I find a ["pure DOM" solution](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/204663/84349). With SimpleXML I can edit the $sx itens of `$sx->xpath('//text()');`, like in the DOM solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the *text content* of a node returned by a SimpleXML XPath query by assigning to `$node[0]`, e.g.

```
foreach ( $sx->xpath('//text()') as $text_node )
{
    $text_node[0] = 'Hello';
}
```

However, beware that SimpleXML does not really have a representation of a *text node* per se, so this kind of loop will behave oddly if there are both child elements and text within an element.

For instance given the XML `<a><b>foo<c />bar</b><b>baz quux</b></a>`, the two text nodes containing `foo` and `bar` will both be represented in SimpleXML by the first `<b>` element, the entire contents of which will be replaced by `'Hello'`, twice over, as shown in the below ([live demo here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3HWFD9)). Using a counter variable in the substituted text, we can see clearly what's happening - the desired output would be `<a><b>Hello 1<c />Hello 2</b><b>Hello 3</b></a>`, but the actual result is `<a><b>Hello 2</b><b>Hello 3</b></a>`.

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string('<a><b>foo<c />bar</b><b>baz quux</b></a>');

$counter = 1;
foreach ( $sx->xpath('//text()') as $text_node )
{
     $text_node[0] = 'Hello ' . $counter++;
}

echo $sx->asXML();
```

This kind of manipulation, at least as you've framed the problem (finding text nodes, rather than iterating, possibly recursively, over a particular set of elements), is much more suited to the DOM API rather than SimpleXML. Bear in mind that there is no performance difference between the two (they are both wrappers around the same XML parser), and that you can combine operations using the two APIs on the same document by using [`simplexml_import_dom()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) and [`dom_import_simplexml()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php), again without additional overhead as the document doesn't need to be re-parsed.

Here is the above example fixed by using a mixture of SimpleXML and DOM ([live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2Vz9lg)). If this were the whole code, you could just parse with DOM directly, but this demonstrates how easy they are to mix if you already have other code manipulating this document with SimpleXML. Note that at the end, we output the XML using the original SimpleXML object - we don't need to run `simplexml_import_dom($dom)`, because both objects refer to the same parsed "document" in memory.

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string('<a><b>foo<c />bar</b><b>baz quux</b></a>');
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($sx);

$counter = 1;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom->ownerDocument);
foreach ( $xpath->query('//text()') as $text_node )
{
     $text_node->nodeValue = 'Hello ' . $counter++;
}

echo $sx->asXML();
```

Comment: Thanks IMSoP! your explanations was shed some light on SimpleXML and my trying to implement the algorithm with it. I understand that is not possiple to implement without "complex" recursive function (your [first example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3HWFD9) not manage the `<c/>` tag). Only the last, a DOM implementation (near the [same as mine](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/204663/84349)) show `<c/>` in the output.