# Xpath Select text

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I have been playing with xpath and I can get it to work when I select paragraphs however this text doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the html

```
<span id="favorite_count" style="display: block;">
    <span style="cursor:help; border-bottom: 1px dotted black;" title="Active members who have made you their favorite.  This number may change as new members join, or close their accounts.">My total number of <span class="favorites">:</span>
    </span> 
19458
</span>
```

I am trying to select `19458`

Here is the xpath Code I have

```
$favorites   = $data->xpath( '//span[@id="favorite_count"]/text()' );
```

NOTE:

I know that it's something to do with this line above because when I use

```
$favorites   = $data->xpath( '//span[@id="favorite_count"]/span' );
```

I get the results of `My total number of`

Also I can't change the HTML because its coming from a page I don't have rights to modify.

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE:

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <span id="favorite_count" style="display: block;">
            <span style="cursor:help; border-bottom: 1px dotted black;" title="Active members who have made you their favorite. This number may change as new members join, or close their accounts.">My total number of <span class="favorites">:</span>
            </span> 
            19458
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE:

```
 /* Use internal libxml errors -- turn on in production, off for debugging */
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
/* Createa a new DomDocument object */
$dom = new DomDocument;
/* Load the HTML */
$dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
/* Create a new XPath object */
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
/* Query all <td> nodes containing specified class name */
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@id='favorite_count']/text()");
/* Set HTTP response header to plain text for debugging output */
header("Content-type: text/plain");
/* Traverse the DOMNodeList object to output each DomNode's nodeValue */
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    echo "Node($i): ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

OUTPUT:

Node(0):

Node(1):
   19458

Answer (score 0):

You are using the SimpleXML library. It can not select textnodes with it's [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) method.

To get that working, you need to extend SimpleXMLElement and adopt the result on the fly. This is easily possible with the help of it's sister library [DOM](http://php.net/dom).

Exemplary Code:

```
echo (new DOMXpath(
   dom_import_simplexml(
      simplexml_load_string($html)
   )->ownerDocument
))->evaluate('normalize-space(//span[@id="favorite_count"]/text()[last()])');
```

Program Output:

> 19458

Demo: https://eval.in/82605

And in your very specific case, you can also do the following directly with SimpleXML:

```
echo trim($xml->xpath('//span[@id="favorite_count"]')[0]);
```

This works because the inner `<span>` does hide the actual node-value, you it only returns the spaces, line-separators and the number 19458.

Related Questions:

- [php xpath with text() and SimpleXMLElement->xpath not in line with xpath expected results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19847451/367456)
- [How to traverse SimpleXML to edit text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631460/367456)